# Save android file preserving its mimetype

Tags: android, mime-types, android-contentresolver, storage-access-framework

I am developing an Android app and need to save file to cache directory. I get file through `ActivityResultContracts`, which returns "content://" uri. Bellow is the function to download (virtual-) file to the cache directory

```
suspend fun createFileSchemeFromContentSchemeUri(context: Context, uri: Uri): Uri? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    if (uri.scheme == ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT) {
        try {
            val stream: InputStream? = getInputStream(context, uri)
            val mimetype: String? = context.contentResolver.getType(uri)
            val fileExtension: String? = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                .getExtensionFromMimeType(mimetype)
                .let {
                    if (it == null) googleVndMimeTypeToExtension.get(mimetype)
                    else it
                }
            var filename: String? = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
                val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                cursor.getString(nameIndex)
            }

            if (stream == null || filename == null || fileExtension == null) return@withContext null

            filename = filename.removeSuffix(".$fileExtension")
            val file = File.createTempFile(filename, ".$fileExtension", context.externalCacheDir)

            stream.use { `in` ->
                file.outputStream().use { out ->
                    val buf = ByteArray(1024 * 1024) // 1MB

                    var len: Int
                    while (`in`.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, len)
                    }
                }
            }

            file.toUri()
        } catch (_: Exception) {
            null
        }
    } else null
}
```

The problem is, that in before copying to output file it is possible to retrieve mimetype (*not always, but most of the time*), but after uri was returned and the same method way to read mimetype is used, i get `null`

**What is the way to preserve original mimetype or "set" it manually?**

I also tried to use FileDescriptor, but it **didn't work**

```
val fileDescriptor = outputStream.fd
fileDescriptor?.let {
    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor)
    fileOutputStream.use {
        FileUtils.copy(
            context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")?.fileDescriptor,
            fileDescriptor
        )
    }
    
    fileOutputStream.flush()
    fileOutputStream.close()
    outputStream.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy. Turns out, that `context.contentResolver.getType(uri)` only works for "content://" based uri-s, which was not right for my case after file was saved to local cache (it became "file://"). Therefor, I updated method to handle both content- and file- based uri-s

```
fun getMimeType(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    if (uri.scheme == ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT) {
        return context.contentResolver.getType(uri)
    } else if (uri.scheme == ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE) {
        val fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString())
        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension)
    } else return null
}
```

Comment: You do not have to care about mimetype as both File.createTempFile and FileOutputStream() do not care about mimetype. And you did not use it either for the destination file.

Comment: @blackapps I dont need it to create temp file or open output stream, you are right, but I need it in this particular case to distinguish photo file from video and do not rely on file extensions on my own.